# font-weight: normal; no funciona en un mensaje de email outlookAppWindow

Tags: html, css, windows, email, outlook

Tengo un pequeño problema con `font-weight: light;` , `font-weight: 100;` , `font-weight: normal;` o `font-weight: regular;` en outlook de Windows aun agregando `"!important"`, siempre se ve en bold y no hay distinción entre `"<strong>"` y los textos que deben estar en light.

Si alguien tiene una idea o sugerencia estaré extremadamente agradecida.

Gracias

Comment: Estás en la versión hispana, edita la pregunta por favor :D

Answer (score 0):

Al revisar los mensajes en el cliente Outlook (con la opción Ver fuente para cualquier mensaje), se puede ver que hay dos opciones:

1) Se define el span con el estilo que se desea

```
<span style='font-size:11.5pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:black;mso-fareast-language:#2000'>Some important text</span>
```

2) El mensaje trae los estilos definidos en el head y después sólo aplica la clase

```
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Helvetica;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head>
...
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=ES-CO>Buen día,<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Comment: no funciono :((

Comment: @CamiEspaña por favor añade más información a la pregunta. Así sin más, estamos adivinando sobre lo que estás intentando y lo que "no funciona". No sabemos cómo se ve ni qué estás tratando de ver.